# Appending and fading the <p> element into a <body>

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML document with some paragraphs. 
I want to do this:

On mouseover, a `div` should be shown to the user, exactly where the paragraph and the mouse cursor is, for the next paragraph, the last `div` should be deleted and new `div` should be appended.

I have written this block of code but I am not able to `fadein`.
Where should I write the code for `fadeout` and how can I set that this `div`  is shown near the paragraph:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('p').hover(function () {
                $('body').append('<div style="position:absolute left= -99px"><p>Hello world</p></div><br/><br/>').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Put it on the position your mouse is?

Comment: yes, on the position of my mouse

Comment: You should rewrite it in jQuery as this I believe won't be parsed as HTML objects. e.g. `$('body').append($('<div />').addClass('colorful').css({position ....}).append($('<p />')` etc.

Comment: A phrase starts with a capital and ends with a dot. Please go through your question and fix this. It makes the question a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite it like this to ensure the objects you wish to append are jQuery objects and actually have the `fadeIn` method and you are able to correctly compute the required position values.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('p').hover(function () {
            $('body').append($('<div />')
                         .addClass('colorful')
                         .css{position : absolute, left : -99})
                         .append($('<p />').html('Hello world'))
                         .fadeIn('slow')
                    );
        });
    });
```

Please check if the number of brackets is correct. I have no syntax checker here.

Comment: Add a little bit of [jquery mouse position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position) and write a function for the [dehover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) part of the hover function which removes the element you just created (e.g. give the div you create a similar ID to that of the <p> tag or whatever (i.e. something that is 'logical' and can easily be recalculated) or store the $(div) you create and apply a `.remove()` or `fadeOut()` to that div.